# Project using postsharp using wrong version on build server

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, postsharp

I have a solution with multiple projects. All of these projects build just fine locally. When I try and build them using my TFS build server, one project throws an error:

> C:\Builds\24\Folder\SolutionName\Sources\Folder\ProjectName.csproj
>   (0, 0)
>       Unhandled exception (4.1.13.0, postsharp.4.0-x64.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.394256, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Error while loading the type "UndoRedo.UndoableAttribute,
>   The.NameSpace.Of.The.Project, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c91567af84d23347": System.IO.FileLoadException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'PostSharp, Version=2.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The problem is I have no idea why it is trying to reference version 2.1.0.0 because the project uses version 4.1.13 of PostSharp.

I have used agent Ransack to search for anything using v2.1.0.0 and nothing shows up. I've checked my project and it is seriously using v4.1.13 (Via NuGet).

Any hints or an answer would be most welcome, thank you.

EDIT: The build works when x86 or x64 is set. The error is thrown with AnyCPU configuration set.

Comment: Do you have any binding redirection for PostSharp in any app.config/web.config file? Do any of nuget dependencies depend on PostSharp? If yes, on which version?

Comment: I checked the binding redirects and I've tried with and without.

Comment: I also simplified the project, and tried building that just in visual studio on the build server (just like it's a dev client) , and that too throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the build output was already a reference registered to the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this info `The error is thrown with AnyCPU configuration set.`  For some complex Solutions with multiple projects that have different configurations, the tokens that you use for configuration and platform must match the tokens that are set up in your solution properties or code project properties. 
[image]

If they do not match, you could experience unexpected results when your build is completed. Pls check this.